# Cost sensitive learning and class balancing

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, unbalanced-classes

I am facing a **classification problem with classes that are really imbalanced** (more or less 1% of positive cases). In addition, **the "cost" of a False Negative (FN) is much higher than the cost of False Negative (FN).**

Considering so, I decided to insert the weights into my classification model. Which the **best way to compute these weights?** Ideally, the weights have to take into account both the data unbalancing and both the miss-classification cost.

I am not interested in putting a 0/1 label to each record, but just in ordering the test dataset according to the output score. The idea is to contact the records with the higher score to offer a product.

I would like to use these weights using, for example, the `sample_weights` parameter available in most of scikit-learn classification algorithm ([here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_sample_weight.html) the documentation).

Is it a good idea to oversample/downsample the data and then use the weight only to control the miss-classification cost? Or should be better to use weights that are able to consider the whole situation? Are there some known ways to compute these weights?